# Losing rep for reviewing the queue

Tags: discussion

I saw a bad answer in the queue, voted it down and got -1 rep. Is this the expected behaviour of this site? If yes, what is the point of reviewing?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is.

Downvoting an answer costs you -1 rep, regardless of whether you got there via a review queue or by any other means. It helps to encourage reviewers to "spend" their downvotes wisely.

If that bothers you, you can avoid downvoting — you can still leave comments explaining what is wrong, etc.

Note also that if the answer is ultimately deleted, you get the rep points back anyway.

Comment: The fundamental law of managing people is "you get what you encourage". To me, rep reduction means "don't do this again", whatever the original intent of the designer was.

Comment: @Oleg: It's only -1, so the message is really "don't do this lightly, but if you see something truly wrong and you're sure, do it.".  This is by design.

Comment: Олег, at least we have *some* mechanism for downvoting.  Most of the non-StackExchange message boards don't have any downvoting mechanism at all.  Negative feedback is generally frowned on in the modern US culture (I'm not saying that that's a good thing).

Answer (score 2):

Oleg, it's a feature.  "Paying" with -1 to yourself when downvoting an *answer* is by design.  The recipient of the downvote suffers -2.

When downvoting *questions*, the downvoter is not suffering -1.

Answer (score 1):

@OlegMazurov the intent is "Sacrifice your rep for the good of the community". If the question or answer isn't bad enough that you are willing to lose a rep point over it, then it's not bad enough to downvote. If you are only in it for the rep, you arn't really participating in a community sense. From https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down:

> **When should I vote down?**
>   Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.
>   You have a limited number of votes per day, and answer down-votes cost you a tiny bit of reputation on top of that; use them wisely.
>
> **What happens when I vote down?**
>   When you vote down, you are nudging that content "down" the page, so it will be seen by fewer people. ***Voting down answers is not something we want you to take lightly, so it is not free.***
>
> **What are the alternatives to down-voting?**
>   The up-vote privilege comes first because that's what you should focus on: pushing great content to the top. Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing.

Think of it as the cost of doing business. A necessary expense to get the point across (pun intended).

That said, there are trade offs for that lost rep. Reviewing can lead to **Badges** which look nicer.